# GDAL C++ RasterIO by blocks

Tags: c++, gdal, rasterio

I am new to gdal and c++ and I am trying to create a function that reads a raster by blocks (using RasterIO and not ReadBlock) do something with the values and writes the result to new raster file

I am getting an error:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFDFB517BC4 (gdal201.dll) in Test.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000230E2593000 at
>   line rasterBand->RasterIO(GDALRWFlag::GF_Read, j * readCols, i *
>   readRows, readCols, readRows, rasterBlock, readCols, readRows,
>   GDALDataType::GDT_CFloat32, 0, 0)

I have a very similar function that works ok, but it reads the pixel values row by row

Any help is appreciated

The function is bellow

Thank you

```
#include <iostream>
#include "gdal_priv.h"
using namespace std;

void SlopeBlock()
{
int readRows = 2048;
int readCols = 2048;
int nBlockXSize;
int nBlockYSize;
int rowOff = 0;
int colOff = 0;
int nRows = 0;
int nCols = 0;
double noData = -9999;

GDALAllRegister();

GDALDataset* dem = (GDALDataset*)GDALOpen("path/EUD_CP-DEMS_4500025000-AA.tif", GA_ReadOnly);

GDALDriver *gTIF = GetGDALDriverManager()->GetDriverByName(dem->GetDriverName());

double geoTransform[6];
dem->GetGeoTransform(geoTransform);

GDALRasterBand* rasterBand = dem->GetRasterBand(1);

nCols = rasterBand->GetXSize();
nRows = rasterBand->GetYSize();
noData = rasterBand->GetNoDataValue();

//rasterBand->GetBlockSize(&nBlockXSize, &nBlockYSize);

int nXBlocks = (rasterBand->GetXSize() + readCols - 1) / readCols;
int nYBlocks = (rasterBand->GetYSize() + readRows - 1) / readRows;

cout << nYBlocks << "___" << nXBlocks << "\n";


//Slope
GDALDataset *slope = gTIF->Create("path/slopeBlock.tif", nCols, nRows, 1, GDT_Float32, NULL);
slope->SetGeoTransform(geoTransform);

for (int i = 0; i < nYBlocks; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < nXBlocks; j++)
    {
        float* rasterBlock = (float*)CPLMalloc(readCols*readRows*sizeof(float));
        float* rasterBlockOut = (float*)CPLMalloc(readCols*readRows*sizeof(float));

        if (rasterBand != nullptr)
            rasterBand->RasterIO(GDALRWFlag::GF_Read, j * readCols, i * readRows, readCols, readRows, rasterBlock, readCols, readRows, GDALDataType::GDT_CFloat32, 0, 0);

        //Not sure if is working
        for (int jb = 0; jb < readCols; jb++)
        {
            if (rasterBlock[jb] == noData)
            {
                rasterBlockOut[jb] = noData;
            }
            else
            {
                rasterBlockOut[jb] = rasterBlock[jb];
            }
        }

        slope->GetRasterBand(1)->RasterIO(GDALRWFlag::GF_Write, j * readCols, i * readRows, readCols, readRows, rasterBlockOut, readCols, readRows, GDALDataType::GDT_CFloat32, 0, 0);

        CPLFree(rasterBlock);
        CPLFree(rasterBlockOut);
    }
}

GDALClose(dem);
GDALClose(slope);
```

}

Comment: GDT_CFloat32 is size of 8 but you are only allocating a size of 4, so it will crash once it reaches the middle of the buffer.  Either change the type to GDT_Float32 or multiply by two for the size of the buffer.  Also your loop method is very slow because you are allocating memory and freeing it inside of the loop.  It is best to just allocate the memory outside of the loop and reuse that same memory and then free it outside of the loop as well.  I used your code above (with my mods) on a slow spinning disk and it read in a 77 MP raster and wrote it to disk within only a few seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the cause of the crash, but you're asking for a 2048*2048 block even if your image is smaller. This code should only work for images with multiples of 2048 as size.

You should do something like:

```
nXSize = min(readCols, rasterBand->GetXSize() - j * readCols);
nYSize = min(readRows, rasterBand->GetYSize() - i * readRows);

rasterBand->RasterIO(GDALRWFlag::GF_Read, j * readCols, i * readRows, 
    nXSize, nYSize, rasterBlock, nXSize, nYSize, GDALDataType::GDT_CFloat32, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. The code bellow is working now, but it takes more time like this than reading the entire image at ones
I changed 
    
 float* rasterBlock = (float*)CPLMalloc(nCols*nRows * sizeof(GDT_CFloat32));
 float* rasterBlockOut = (float*)CPLMalloc(nCols*nRows * sizeof(GDT_CFloat32));

Comment: The purpose of working with blocks is not to speed up the processing (if you process the whole image) but to be able to handle a quantity of data that wouldn't fit in ram. If you can load the whole image at once in ram, it will for sure be quicker.